# Open PDF file on the fly from a Java application

Tags: java, pdf

Is there any way to have a code that opens a PDF file in Java application in a platform independant way? I mean using a batch file in Windows could do that. Is there any other way to have a platform independent code to open PDF files on the fly?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Do you mean as in "launch Adobe Reader to display a specific PDF document"?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't specifically define the "open". Yup, as what you thought of. ;)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I'd try [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)), which:

> Launches the associated application to open the file.

So this code should do the trick:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 What would you do if you want the pdf file to be opened in your own app so that you can interact with it in your own way? Thanks.

Comment: @chepukha: In that case, this code should be irrelevant to you, as your PDF-reading component should have its own methods for loading a file.

Comment: yes, I understand that. Should I make another question for that?

Comment: @chepukha: If you're having trouble with it, sure, no reason not to.

Comment: Although the general idea is correct (and works!), this syntax is incorrect for Java 6; check here for correct syntax:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html.  And +1 for non-Windows-only solution.

Comment: I just pasted it in Java 8 code, still works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Runtime to execute and script and there are also several Java PDF viewers out there (ie Icepdf, JPedal, PDFRenderer).

Answer (score 2):

Use this to open pdf file using java

```
File file = new File(filepath);
    if (file.toString().endsWith(".pdf")) 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file);
    else {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        desktop.open(file);
}
```

This code is used to open your pdf and other files.

Comment: This solution works fine on Windows, but is not platform independent which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Meyer's solution didn't quite work for me. Specifically, a path with spaces fails with an IllegalArgumentException rather than an IOException.

Here's what works for me:

```
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
try {
File theUMFile = new File(usersManualPath);
 Desktop.getDesktop().open(theUMFile);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException fnf){
okDialog(msg_fnf);
theConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, null, fnf);
theConcours.GetLogger().info(msg_fnf);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException fnf) {
 okDialog(msg_fnf);
            theConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, null, fnf);
            theConcours.GetLogger().info(msg_fnf);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            okDialog(msg_cno);
            theConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            theConcours.GetLogger().info(msg_cno);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

3-rd party applications can not access src dir in your application, in case, when your app assemble in jar archive. You should place your file separately from src.

Of course, java find icons, because it's java API. You can access any resources in src folder through follow methods:

```
 URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/in/src");
 File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

I am currently using the below:

```
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
             try {
                    URL url = getClass().getResource("/pdf/XXXX.pdf");
                    File myFile = new File(url.toURI());
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                        // no application registered for PDFs
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this code to open a specific file:

```
String cmds[] = new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\EA01.pdf"};
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
}
```