# how to open a pdf file from java?

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

I want to open a PDF file from a jsp. The jsp and the PDF are in the same directory.
I am using the following piece of code:

```
if (Desktop.isSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("<file name>.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```

However, I get the error that the file is not found.
Verified user.dir and it points to my tomcat/bin.
How can I refer to the pdf to open it?

Comment: Got the code from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546968/open-pdf-file-on-fly-from-java-application/2547004#2547004

Comment: above code will open PDF on server if desktop is availabe, you should use forward or redirect from jsp to pdf to expose it to user

Comment: gertas, can you give me a code sample to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the absolute file path. Assuming that there's a `filename.pdf` in the root of the public webcontent, this should do:

```
File myFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/filename.pdf"));
```

However, this construct won't work the way you'd expect. It will show the PDF file in webserver machine, not in webbrowser machine! Only when you happen to run both the webserver and webbrowser at **physically the same** machine, this will "work". But this does obviously not happen in real world when you publish your webapp into the internet where the webserver and webbrowser runs at physically different machines.

Instead, you just need to link to the PDF file directly.

```html
<a href="filename.pdf">View PDF</a>
```

and let the browser handle the display.

Comment: I have it working the HTML way. But, I really want to know how to make it work from java/jsp.

Comment: You really need to realize that Java/JSP code runs in webserver, not in webbrowser. All the webbrowser runs is HTML/CSS/JS which is generated and sent by Java/JSP. If you want to run Java code in webbrowser, you'd need to create an [applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) and embed it as `<applet>` in HTML page. This is however terribly clumsy if all you want is to show a PDF file to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I just got this from google, so I dunno if it will work.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:\\Java-    Interview.pdf");
        p.waitFor();
```