# How to add pdf files to NetBeans project?

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans

I'd like to be able to open pdf files in a NetBeans project like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547004/398460) for a help menu but I don't see a way to add the pdf files to the project in a way that they will become part of the distribution. The application needs to be able to find the pdf files. I thought there might be an option to add the files to the project resources but this doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: Go for relatives path taking into consideration the pathing of diferent OS.
If you store those files lets say within a folder called files. and use a installer to distribute the project and that folder they'll be within reach of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a resource folder in your project then just copy it in there and then `clean and build`

or right-click on the  folder and create a package 
folder called "documents". Put your pdf in there and clean-and-build.

Comment: What then is the path of file.pdf? I've tried file.pdf, /resources/file.pdf, ../resources/file.pdf, and ./resources/file.pdf.

Comment: Never mind--found it: `new File(new File(new File("src", "project"), "resources"), "file.pdf")`