# File is not opening in java which is inside jar file

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I tried to open file form my java application. Using following code from

[Open PDF file on fly from Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546968/open-pdf-file-on-fly-from-java-application)

Code:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```

When I use path like :

```
"C:\\Users\\kalathoki\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TestJava\\src\\files\\test.pdf"
```

it opens. But my file is inside my package

```
files/test.pdf
```

and I used

```
files\\test.pdf
```

it shows following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: \files\test.pdf doesn't exist.
```

Why? Any Idea... I want to include my file inside my jar file that can open from my application whenever user wants.

Thanks...

Comment: if the file of this class is inside src , then change your path to **files/test.pdf**

Comment: Why do you use `files\\test.pdf` to open `files/test.pdf`?

Comment: @Tichodroma actually `C:\\Users\\kalathoki\\Documents...` worked so I tried `files\\test.pdf` and `test.pdf` file is inside `files` package

Comment: Did you try new `path/to` instead of `/path/to` ? new can also try to display the absolute path of `new File(".");` it will certainly help

Comment: @FaceOfJock and Arnaud Denoyelle it doesnot work and I tried many times... Did not resolve problem and I asked to stack-overflow.

Comment: Can it, by any chance just be "/path/to/file.pdf.pdf"?

Comment: where is your actual class in your project ? show us structure of your project

Comment: @FaceOfJock inside another package like `abc`

Comment: I did not read the `I want to keep my file inside my project jar file.` part, sorry. Use `InputStream is = System.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file.pdf");` to get it as an `InputStream`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I confused  and asked here... Yes...It may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getDesktop#open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) only allows files to be opened from the file system. One solution is to keep the PDF file locally on the file system and read from there. This eliminates extracting the file from the JAR itself so is more efficient.

Comment: Actually it's not true, under Linux getDesktop().open() permits to open files inside a jar, Windows apparently doesn' permit it. In the documentation you linked they don't mention the limitation you described.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot load a file through Desktop that is contained in the jar.

However, you are not out of options. A great workaround is to create a temporary file and then open it as detailed [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/456579/java/java/open-pdf-file-located-jar).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming test.pdf is in the package files, try this:

```
File myFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/files/test.pdf").toURI());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working properly please use this to open pdf file within jar file

```
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String path = jTextField1.getText();
        System.out.println(path);
        Path tempOutput = null;
        String tempFile = "myFile";
        tempOutput = Files.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
        tempOutput.toFile().deleteOnExit();
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/JCADG.pdf");
        Files.copy(is,tempOutput,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
        {
            Desktop dTop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if(dTop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN))
            {
                dTop.open(tempOutput.toFile());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
```