# The file which is inside package, not opening from java application

Tags: java, file, pdf, file-io

Dear experts this question is associated with

- [File is not opening in java which is inside jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010013/file-is-not-opening-in-java-which-is-inside-jaf-file)

**Updated Question**

And I used two codes from:

- [open a pdf file located inside a jar file](http://www.coderanch.com/t/456579/java/java/open-pdf-file-located-jar)

Following code works fine if I run application from `workspace`.

```
URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("resources/User_Guide.pdf");  
            File userGuideFile = null;  
            try {  
                userGuideFile = new File(resource.getPath());  
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())  
                {  
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();  
                    desktop.open(userGuideFile);  
                }  
            } catch (Exception e1) {  
                e1.printStackTrace();  
            }
```

But If I copy my `project.jar` to another location it will not opens file and shows in my log as `file is not found "c:\workspace\project...pdf"`. And I used following code from [same page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/456579/java/java/open-pdf-file-located-jar) , My **pdfReader** adobe reader shows exception  `file is either not supproted or damaged` :

**Code:**

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())     
{     
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();     
    InputStream resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("resources/User_Guide.pdf");  
try  
{  
    File file = File.createTempFile("User_Guide", ".pdf");  
    file.deleteOnExit();  
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    try  
    {  
        // copy contents from resource to out  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
        out.close();  
    }  
    desktop.open(file);     
}     
finally  
{  
    resource.close();  
}  
}
```

Please give me some idea. Your help will be appreciated. Thank You

**Note:** I tried to open `*.txt` file and it is working fine. But not working in `PDF` and `DOC`. The main problem is when I run application changing the project work-space directory. Actually I want to make like:  **Ntebeans keyboard-short-code documents which is under `Help` menu**

Comment: Another location within the same workspace or different workspace of different Computer

Comment: Same computer another location eg: `my workspace inside E:\workspace` and I copy my jar file to `D:\apps`. I have to distribute my application more than 50 computers...

Comment: Does the new path contains `spaces`?

Comment: @AdeelAnsari There is no space

Comment: There are no files, or Files, inside packages. There are only resources. Resources have URLs, and URLs have streams, but URLs are not filenames. You're using the wrong technique here.

Comment: @EJP Sir, Please see my **Note** which is in footer of my question. What I actually want and tell me what is the exact technique to resolve this issue? please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jar is a zip archive. So first look into it with 7zip/WinZip or the like.
Check that in it the path is indeed `resources/User_Guide.pdf` (case sensitive!).
It might very well be `/User_Guide.pdf` in the jar.

One cannot immediately get a File (=file on the file system) from a resource (only by accident). So one gets an `InputStream`.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResource("/resources/User_Guide.pdf");
```

`NullPointerException` when not found. With getClass the class must be in the same jar, and the path in this case starting with a `/`.

Now you can copy the input stream to some temporary file, and open that. In Java 7:

```
File file = File.createTempFile("User_Guide", ".pdf");  
Files.copy(in, file.toPath());
```

If you get a FileAlreadyExistsException in the Files.copy line, then add the following CopyOption:

```
Files.copy(in, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

For java <7:

```
// copy contents from resource to out
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
while ((int nread = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, nread);
}
```

Comment: [File.toPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath%28%29) exists only since Java 7. For a prior version, if you do not want to reinvent the wheel, there exists apache commons io classes to do such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Joop Eggen's accepted answer, but the line

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResource("/resources/User_Guide.pdf");
```

throws the error "Incompatible types: URL cannot be converted to InputStream". Instead use the method getResourceAsStream():

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/User_Guide.pdf");
```