# Open a PDF file using the path from the JTextField - Swing

Tags: java, swing

Have small GUI, on-click **Open** button trying to open the pdf document stored locally and the file path is in the JTextField.

[image]

I couldn't get it, Please give me some directions, thanks.

So Far the code;

```
        JButton btnEdi = new JButton("Open");
    btnEdi.setMnemonic('o');
    btnEdi.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnEdi.setBorder(null);
    btnEdi.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    btnEdi.setBounds(378, 621, 35, 19);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(btnEdi);

    btnEdi.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        //desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        //String storedFileName = txtText.getText();
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            desktop.open(txtText.getText());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe this help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546968/open-pdf-file-on-fly-from-java-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this line:

```
btnEdi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override // don0t forget @Override annotation
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        desktop.open(txtText.getText()); // here
    }
});
```

According to [Desktop#open(File file)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) method documentation it takes a [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object as argument, not a `String`, so I doubt your code even compiles. It also throws an [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) that has to be treated.

That being said, this is what I'd do:

```
btnEdi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        File pdfFile = new File(txtText.getText());                
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null
                                         , "An error happened trying to open file : " + pdfFile.getPath()
                                         , "IOException"
                                         , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
            );
        }
    }
});
```

See also [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks @dic19, that was a brilliant solution!! Thank you so much. my code didn't even compile, was throwing an error, after a long struggle have posted it. It worked now, Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the isDesktopSupported() method to determine whether the Desktop API is available on your operation system.

```
File pdfFile = new File("resources\\ManoeuvreRules-2010.pdf");   
if(isDesktopSupported()){
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null
                                     , "An error happened trying to open file : " + pdfFile.getPath()
                                     , "IOException"
                                     , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
        );
    }
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null
                                     , "This is not supported on your Operating System: " 
                                     , "IOException"
                                     , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
        );
}
```